# WCF Service for insert into MS SQL Server

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, wcf

I developed an app for Android that should consume WCF service and insert using JSON Advertisement record into MS SQL Server database. I don't know why it doesn't insert new rows in the database, can you help me figure out where is the error?
Service1.svc.sc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration; 

namespace wcf_ads_Proj
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdsCon"].ConnectionString);

        public string InsertAdsRegDetails(RegDetails adsregdet)
        {
            string Status;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbl_Ads(Ads_Content,Ads_Category,Ads_Phone) VALUES (@Ads_Content, @Ads_Category, @Ads_Phone)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Content", adsregdet.Ads_Content);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Category", adsregdet.Ads_Category);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Phone", adsregdet.Ads_Phone);

            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Status = adsregdet.Ads_Content +  " registered successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                Status = adsregdet.Ads_Content + " could not be registered";
            }
            con.Close();
            return Status;
        }

        public DataSet GetAdsRegDetails()
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Tbl_Ads", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }

        public DataSet FetchUpdatedRecords(RegDetails regdet)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Tbl_Ads where Ads_ID=@Ads_ID", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_ID", regdet.Ads_ID);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }

        public string UpdateAdsRegDetails(RegDetails regdet)
        {
            string Status;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Tbl_Ads set Ads_Content=@Ads_Content,Ads_Category=@Ads_Category,Ads_Phone=@Ads_Phone where Ads_ID=@Ads_ID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_ID", regdet.Ads_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Content", regdet.Ads_Content);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Category", regdet.Ads_Category);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Phone", regdet.Ads_Phone);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", regdet.Password);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", regdet.ContactNo);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Status = "Record updated successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                Status = "Record could not be updated";
            }
            con.Close();
            return Status;
        }
        public bool DeleteAdsRegDetails(RegDetails regdet)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from Tbl_Ads where Ads_ID=@Ads_ID", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserRegId", regdet.Ads_ID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }

        public string InsertAds(RegDetails regdet)
        {
            string Status;
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbl_Ads(Ads_Content,Ads_Category,Ads_Phone) VALUES (@Ads_Content, @Ads_Category, @Ads_Phone)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Content", regdet.Ads_Content);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Category", regdet.Ads_Category);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ads_Phone", regdet.Ads_Phone);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", regdet.Password);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", regdet.ContactNo);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                Status = regdet.Ads_Content + " registered successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                Status = regdet.Ads_Content + " could not be registered";
            }
            con.Close();
            return Status;
        }

    }
}
```

IService1.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace wcf_ads_Proj
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "Get",
            UriTemplate = "RegAds",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string InsertAds(RegDetails regdet);       

        [OperationContract]
        string InsertAdsRegDetails(RegDetails regdet);

        [OperationContract]
        DataSet GetAdsRegDetails();

        [OperationContract]
        DataSet FetchUpdatedRecords(RegDetails regdet);

        [OperationContract]
        string UpdateAdsRegDetails(RegDetails regdet);

        [OperationContract]
        bool DeleteAdsRegDetails(RegDetails regdet);
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    [DataContract]
    public class RegDetails
    {
         int p_Ads_ID;
        string p_Ads_Content = string.Empty;
        String p_Ads_Date = string.Empty;
        string p_Ads_Phone = string.Empty;
        string p_Ads_Category = string.Empty;

        [DataMember]
        public int Ads_ID
        {
            get { return p_Ads_ID; }
            set { p_Ads_ID = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Ads_Content
        {
            get { return p_Ads_Content; }
            set { p_Ads_Content = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Ads_Date
        {
            get { return p_Ads_Date; }
            set { p_Ads_Date = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Ads_Phone
        {
            get { return p_Ads_Phone; }
            set { p_Ads_Phone = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Ads_Category
        {
            get { return p_Ads_Category; }
            set { p_Ads_Category = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

**AddMemberActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.twittersearch;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONStringer;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddMemberActivity extends Activity {


    private class SendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText TxtContent=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
                String content=TxtContent.getText().toString();
                EditText TxtCategory=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtPassword);
                String category=TxtCategory.getText().toString();
                EditText txtPhone=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.TxtCountry);
                String country=txtPhone.getText().toString();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.sayedyousif.com/ads_wcf/Service1.svc/RegAds");
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            JSONStringer GetUserInfo;
            try {
                GetUserInfo = new JSONStringer()

                        .object()
                        .key("regdet")
                            .object()
                                .key("Ads_Content").value(content)                                  
                                .key("Ads_Category").value(category)
                                .key("Ads_Phone").value(country)
                            .endObject()
                         .endObject();

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(GetUserInfo.toString());
                Log.d("Test", GetUserInfo.toString());
            request.setEntity(entity);

            // Send request to WCF service
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_member);

        Button btnadd=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SendPostData sendpostdata=new SendPostData();
                sendpostdata.execute();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_member, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did your data reach from android to WCF Service....?

Comment: Show us exactly what error/problem you have

Answer (score 0):

In yor WCF you are using

> WebInvoke(Method = "Get" //(Calling a GET)

And AddMemberActivity.java are calling a POST

Comment: So do you recommend changing it to WebInvoke(Method="Post")

Comment: Piyush, My android json didn't move to WCF service, but when I implemented other like this http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations it worked!